# How to fix the issues when I update wordpress in php 7

Tags: wordpress-theming

please help me to fix. 
I have updated the PHP 5.6 to php7.3. 
But the WordPress sites don't work well. 
As you can see, the new site's below is not working despite the same code and the same database.
I have replaced the '& new' to 'new' based on the StackOverflow's answer. I appreciate if you give me the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see what is wrong on the new website. Have you fixed? My hint for you is to enable the WordPress DEBUG in the wp-config file. With this you can see the code that is not working.

Comment: Thanks.
I have fixed it.
I added some codes in the wp-config.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thanks.
I added some codes in the wp-config.php

ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); 
And I updated  the customLoop function in the PeThemeContent.php
public function customLoop($type,$count = 10,$tax = null,$custom = null,$paged = false) {
        $args = $this->getPostsQueryArgs($type,$count,$tax,$custom,$paged);
    if ($this->current) {
        $this->loops[] = $this->current;
    }
    $this->master->data->postSave();
    $this->current = new WP_Query($args);
    return $this->current->post_count > 0;
}
```

So, the issue is solved.